# dplyr filter "cell content" "cell value" is

Tags: r, dplyr, package

This is a **basic question but I spent 2 hours seaching for the answer and I didnt find how to solve that**. I have a Likert scale (0,5,10), but, unfortunately, my dataset has some different values from that (e.g., 800). I wrote a reproductible code.

I want to use dplyr to keep only the rows where I have only 0,5,10 (or to drop the entire row where I have a weird results)

Example
Code:

```
dat <- data.frame(v1=c(10,5,0,10), 
                  v2=c(10,0,0,800), 
                  v3=c(10,0,0,5), 
                  v4=c(800,10,5,10),
                  v5=c(0,800,5,10))
```

I know I can use something like that:

```
dat2 <- dat %>% filter(rowSums(.) < 50)
```

But I want to "loop" all dataset to drop the rows where I have different numbers from what I´m expecting.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to 'loop' over? Do you have more than one of these datasets?

Comment: Instead of dropping the whole row, can you just do something like `mutate_at(vars(v1:v5), function(x) ifelse(x %in% c(0,5,10), x, NA))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `filter_all` with `all_vars`:

```
dat
#  v1  v2 v3  v4  v5
#1 10  10 10 800   0
#2  5   0  0  10 800
#3  0   0  0   5   5
#4 10 800  5  10  10

filter_all(dat, all_vars(. %in% c(0,5,10)))
#  v1 v2 v3 v4 v5
#1  0  0  0  5  5
```

Comment: Thanks, @Psidom. I was looking for that!